# Is there a way to select all the contents of a node?

Tags: xml, ruby, utf-8, nokogiri

Is there a way to select all the contents of a node in Nokogiri?

```
<root>
    <element>this is <hi>the content</hi> of my æøå element</element>
</root>
```

The result of getting the content of `/root/element` should be:

```
this is <hi>the content</hi> of my æøå element
```

---

Edit:

It seems like the solution is simply to use `myElement.inner_html()`. The problem I had was in fact that I was relying on an old version of libxml2, which escaped all the special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Nokogiri.parse('<root><element>this is <hi>the content</hi> of my element</element></root>').css('element').inner_html
```

If you want escape that, you can with `CGI.unescape` method:

```
require 'cgi'
x = Nokogiri.parse('<root><element>this is <hi>the content</hi> of my element</element></root>').css('element').inner_html
CGI.unescape(x)
```

Comment: Nokogiri.parse('<root><element>this is <hi>the content</hi> of my æøå  element</element></root>').css('element').inner_html.inspect
=> "\"this is <hi>the content</hi> of my &#xE6;&#xF8;&#xE5;  element\""

Comment: You can CGI.unescape the result

Comment: Hmm, maybe unescaped works for your test cases, but you are potentially unescaping something that wasn't escaped initially. Might see if the [loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) gem helps in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous answer is assuming HTML. I'm not sure that's appropriate, so here's my (similar) answer:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = '<root><element>this is <hi>the content</hi> of my æøå element</element></root>' 
p Nokogiri(xml).at('element').to_xml
```